# 100% tall <li> elements without using position:absolute trick?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to have a simple HTML layout with several `<li>` elements inline, each of which has a `height:100%`

I have used the following CSS trick to accomplish this:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
```

[See my JSFiddle for an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/kVwRC/7/)

For reasons outside the scope of this question, I desire to NOT have my `<li>` elements positioned absolutely. Can someone chime in on how to achieve this same layout with `position:relative;` or `position:static;` `<li>` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kVwRC/13/).

The `<li>` elements are floated left and use the `display:inline-block` rule to get the proper height and width. Floating also removes the need for the rules; `li.one { left:0; }
li.two { left:33%; } li.three { left:66%; }`

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul {
    /* width:100%; */
    /* height:500px; */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    height:100%;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    background:#333;
    color:white;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    background:#666;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to set the left position dynamically, say with javascript?  That was the reason for having the `left` there in the first place.

Comment: I will also need to be able to dynamically set the width of each `<li>`